# Nginx proxy_pass with variables

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location, nginx-upstreams

I've got 2 upstreams and described the logic of cookie check in nginx config:

```
upstream back {
    server backend-release.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local;
 }
upstream back-preprod {
    server backend-preprod.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local;
}

map $http_cookie $back_upstream {
    default back;
    ~*is-preprod=true back-preprod;
}

location ~ ^/(api|graphql) {
    proxy_pass http://$back_upstream;
}
location /rest/ {
    proxy_pass http://$back_upstream/rest/;
}
```

When i call GET http://my-url/api/..., it works, but i always get 404 for GET http://my-url/rest/..

How to fix it?

Comment: Try `proxy_pass http://$back_upstream;` without the `/rest/`

Comment: Same result: 404

Answer (score 1):

I found solution:

```
upstream back {
    server backend-release.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local;
}
upstream back-preprod {
    server backend-preprod.mynamespace.svc.cluster.local;
}

map $http_cookie $back_upstream {
    default back;
    ~*is-preprod=true back-preprod;
}

location ~ ^/(api|graphql|rest) {
    proxy_pass http://$back_upstream;
}
```

`location /rest/` is unnecessary in this case.